# Two questions about integration

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

1. Suppose that I have differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt} = a(t)b(x)$, where $a(\cdot):I\to\mathbb{R}$ and $b(\cdot):J\to\mathbb{R}$. Let $J_0=\{x\in J\,|\,b(x)\neq0\}$. On $J_0$, when we "separate" variables we obtain $\frac{dx}{b(x)}=a(t)dt$. My question is following.
   When I integrate this equality, what I get? $\int\frac{dx}{b(x)}=\int a(t)dt$? And why i get this?
2. If I have 2 functions $f$ and $g$ with $f(x)=g(t)$, then I have $\int f(x) dx = \int g(t) dx$ or I have $\int f(x) dx = \int g(t) dt$?

Comment: 1. differentiate your first equation to get the differential equation. 2. f(x)=g(t) makes no sense a function depends on x or on t.

Answer (score 1):

1. You get $$\int \frac{dx}{b(x)} = \int a(t)\; dt + C$$
   where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.  Note however that solutions in different intervals of $J_0$
   are not connected to each other and represent different solutions, whether or not they have the same $C$.

The convenient notation actually obscures what's really going on here, and I think that's causing your confusion. The variable $x$ is supposed to be a function of $t$, say $x = X(t)$, the differential equation says $X'(t) = a(t) b(X(t))$, so
$$\frac{X'(t)}{b(X(t))} = a(t)$$
Now both sides are integrated with respect to the **same** variable $t$:
$$ \int \dfrac{X'(t)}{b(X(t))}\; dt = \int a(t)\; dt + C$$
but on the left side we use the substitution $X(t) = x$, so if $F(x) $ is an antiderivative of $1/b(x)$  the result is $F(X(t)) = \int a(t)\; dt + C$.